# Displaying only plain html in browser - problem vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've got task with I'm struggling a day, to do but I'm trying to figure out why vuetify components aren't visible. How did they write in task I need to resend this file so I'm thinking all code should be put in ui.html

My task looks like that:

`ui.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Task</h1>
    <p>Please download this file and prepare nice UI using provided data.<br>
    For task you can use <a href="https://vuetifyjs.com/" target="_blank">Vuetify</a> with minimal (if any) additional style.</p>
    <p>In response please send this file with your UI proposal.</p>

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    workerList: [
            {
                "gender":"male",
                "name":{
                    "first":"Brian",
                    "last":"Adams"
                },
                "location":{
                    "street":{
                        "number":734,
                        "name":"Park Road"
                    },
                    "city":"Stoke-on-Trent",
                    "state":"County Fermanagh",
                    "country":"United Kingdom",
                    "postcode":"XR3 9EY",
                    "coordinates":{
                        "latitude":"18.0015",
                        "longitude":"-86.0374"
                    }
                },
                "email":"brian.adams@example.com",
                "registered":"2008-11-07T11:53:14.120Z",
                "phone":"015394 84142",
                "cell":"0737-492-043",
                "isActive": true,
                "picture":{
                    "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/42.jpg",
                    "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/42.jpg"
                },
                "nationality":"GB"
            }
        ]
  },
    computed: {
    perState() {
      return this.workerList.reduce((acc, i) => {
        acc[i.location.state] = (acc[i.location.state] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
    }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And when I put something from vuetify between `<div id="app"> </div>` something like

```
  <v-alert
      border="top"
      color="red lighten-2"
      dark
    >
      I'm an alert with a top border and red color
    </v-alert>
```

then I'm only seeing plain html without style from vue like in the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to link css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Task</h1>
    <p>Please download this file and prepare nice UI using provided data.<br>
    For task you can use <a href="https://vuetifyjs.com/" target="_blank">Vuetify</a> with minimal (if any) additional style.</p>
    <p>In response please send this file with your UI proposal.</p>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-container>
            <v-alert
              border="top"
              color="red lighten-2"
              dark
            >
              I'm an alert with a top border and red color
            </v-alert>
          </v-container>
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
    </div>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      workerList: [{"gender":"male", "name":{"first":"Brian", "last":"Adams"}, "location":{"street":{ "number":734, "name":"Park Road"}, "city":"Stoke-on-Trent",  "state":"County Fermanagh", "country":"United Kingdom", "postcode":"XR3 9EY",  "coordinates":{"latitude":"18.0015", "longitude":"-86.0374"}},   "email":"brian.adams@example.com", "registered":"2008-11-07T11:53:14.120Z",  "phone":"015394 84142", "cell":"0737-492-043", "isActive": true, "picture":{         "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/42.jpg", "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/42.jpg"}, "nationality":"GB"}]
      }
  },
  computed: {
    perState() {
      return this.workerList.reduce((acc, i) => {
        acc[i.location.state] = (acc[i.location.state] || 0) + 1;
        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
  }
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```